# Add a link about jTab to the editing help page

Tags: feature-request, jtab, editing

I know I can find it if I search for it, but wouldn't it be cool if it were linked from [the editing-help page](https://music.stackexchange.com/editing-help)?

Comment: Presumably it's possible -- math.se has LaTeX info on their editing help page: http://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latex. Looks like we probably need SE staff to do it, though.

Comment: Now that ABCjs is available, this should also be linked here

Comment: MathJax is implemented on a bunch of sites, whereas jTab and ABCjs are implemented on just this site – so I don't foresee this happening for either one.

Answer (score 3):

We still lack the documentation AND the mention `<pre></pre>` prevents jTab to render.

I was kind of lost when I wrote this answer: https://music.stackexchange.com/posts/31438/revisions